# Meaning of $\wedge$ in this equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

What is $\{ \rho( \xi_n, \xi) \wedge 1\}$ in the following equation?

[image]

Comment: I suspect $x\wedge y=\min(x,y)$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wedge symbol $\wedge$ is sometimes used to mean this function

$$
(f\wedge g)(x) \;\; =\;\; \min\{f(x), g(x)\}
$$

which is defined at each point $x$.  This can actually be expressed equivalently as:

$$
(f\wedge g)(x) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}\left [f(x) + g(x) - |f(x) - g(x)| \right ].
$$

In your particular example, it appears that the context in which they present it is the minimum between the distance of two random elements and the constant 1:
$$
\rho(\xi_n, \xi) \wedge 1 \;\; =\;\; \min\{\rho(\xi_n, \xi), 1\}.
$$